# linphone android login error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: setUsername

Tags: android, linphone

linphone for android compiled success,and I import the "linphone-android" project to Eclipse,run it in my android phone.But when I add a account or login,throw a exception:

No implementation found for native Lorg/linphone/core/LinphoneAuthInfoImpl;.setUsername (JLjava/lang/String;)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: setUsername

[image: linphone-android libs Directory]

I think the question is have not load .so librarys,Log shows:

```
No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.linphone/lib/libxxx.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this solution:

Go to submodules/linphone/coreapi/linphonecore_jni.cc

Edit linphonecore_jni.cc file.

The change is - replace JNIEXPORT with extern "C" and remove JNICALL keyword in all this getter / setters of linphone auth info.

```
/*
 * Class:     org_linphone_core_LinphoneAuthInfoImpl
 * Method:    setUsername
 * Signature: (JLjava/lang/String;)V
 */
extern "C" void Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneAuthInfoImpl_setUsername (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jlong auth_info, jstring jusername) {
const char* username = jusername?env->GetStringUTFChars(jusername, NULL):NULL;
linphone_auth_info_set_username((LinphoneAuthInfo*)auth_info,username);
if (username) env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jusername, username);
}
```

refer to [Kaushik Parmar's solution](http://nongnu.13855.n7.nabble.com/setUsername-method-not-found-td167790.html).